# Как создать кнопку с повторным разрешением на включение камеры в SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Я выполняю проект с камерой на SwiftUI, я добавил разрешения в info.plist для работы камеры. Проблема в том, что если пользователь не даст разрешения, то камера не будет работать. Я хочу добавить кнопку, когда вы нажимаете на нее, снова появляется запрос на включение камеры. Или же хотя бы как снова вызвать запрос, пока пользователь не согласится его включить? Я просмотрел различные статьи и видео, я не нашел никакой информации, я буду благодарен вам за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот например как можно вызывать запрос на доступ к камере:

```
class CameraManager : ObservableObject {
    @Published var permissionGranted = false
    
    func requestPermission() {
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video, completionHandler: {accessGranted in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.permissionGranted = accessGranted
            }
        })
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var cameraManager = CameraManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world")
            if cameraManager.permissionGranted {
                //show a conditional view only if you have permission
            }
        }
        .onReceive(cameraManager.$permissionGranted, perform: { (granted) in
            if granted {
                //show image picker controller
            }
        })
        .onAppear {
            cameraManager.requestPermission()
        }
    }
}
```

проверять есть ли уже разрешение можно так:

```
if AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) ==  .authorized {
    //already authorized
} else {
    AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video, completionHandler: { (granted: Bool) in
        if granted {
            //access allowed
        } else {
            //access denied
        }
    })
}
```